# Как добавить текст внутрь эллипса?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс который позволяет нарисовать эллипс по координатам x, y на канвасе. Как можно добавить текст внутрь эллипса?

```
class draw
{
    public static void circle(double x, double y, int width, int height, Canvas cv)
    {

        Ellipse circle = new Ellipse()
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            StrokeThickness = 6
        };

        cv.Children.Add(circle);

        circle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)x);
        circle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (double)y);
    }
}

draw.circle(x, y, 10, 10, cavRoot);
```

Comment: Это точно WPF? Почему вы рисуете как в WinForms? А так, создайте `TextBlock` с нужными координатами, и поместите в него текст, а его самого в `Canvas`.

Comment: Эллипс можно получить из Border с нужными CormerRadius, ну а текст поместить в него — еще проще